# Different methods to normalize images

Tags: image, image-processing

I want to normalize images whose pixel can have negative values and found two different ways to do that. Given a two-dimensional matrix `X` I can do the following:

a) `X = 0.5*((X/max(abs(X))+1)`

b) `X = (X-min(X))/(max(X)-min(X))`

Since I'm not an expert, I'm not sure which of the two is the more useful way to normalize images. Does one of the two options have certain advantages?

Comment: Choice of the method depends on what you want to do with the normalized images. For example, if you are planning to use them for a machine learning task, it may be better to use techniques that are often used for normalizing images in these types of tasks.

Comment: You can also do `X/max(abs(X))`, or `X/std(X)`, or... The question is: what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I am just not sure which method to use. I have matrices with positive and negative elements which I want to shift such that all elements are positive without loosing to much information. I wondered if one method has any advantages.

Comment: @Samuel: Yes, but that doesn’t answer my (granted, poorly wriiten) question: what will you do with the result? Why do you need only non-negative values? What processing comes after?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I need to convert the matrices into images with positive pixel values to do structural analysis (GLCM). I wondered, if one method is especially useful for that purpose?

Answer (score 1):

For GLCM is does not at all matter where the 0 level is, what matters is the differences between intensities. Thus, I would pick the method that linearly stretches between the min and max intensity. This method uses the output range best, and therefore introduced the least quantization error.

When comparing GLCM results across images, it is best if all images are stretched the same way. I would select a global min and max, keep those constant for all images in the set.

---

Note that for other purposes, the answer will be different.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach will use the full range between 0 and 1, which may be what you want. The first approach will map 0 always to 0.5. When the data is symmetrically spread around 0, also the first approach will use the full range between 0 and 1.

Up to you to decide what you want.